# Circular progress bar in angular 2

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular2-template

I am trying to create a percentage loader in angular 2. The Loader should load the amount of given percentage and it should be dynamic.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 bar">
  <div class="c100 p50 small">
    <span>50%</span>
    <div class="slice">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="fill"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="textP">
    <h3>Statistic 1</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have created one by using CSS for 50% but it's not dynamic. When i change the percentage it loads only the previous value 50%. Do I have to use ngModel or anything.

Comment: Can you show your component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a component circular-percent-loader which you include in your parent component like ,

```
<circular-percent-loader [percent]="percent"></circular-percent-loader>
```

Here percent is the input for your child component.In the child component, 
you can take this and set the percentage like this.I am supposing you take the 50% from this span.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 bar">
                <div class="c100 p50 small">
                    <span>{{percent}}</span>
                    <div class="slice">
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                        <div class="fill"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="textP">
                    <h3>Statistic 1</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
```

In child component.ts

```
@Input() percent: number;
```

Comment: Or you can use this - https://github.com/Feridum/angular2-circle-progress

Comment: Hi @RemyaJ could u or Musheer please give a working codepen or something , it would really give a hang of it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's create ngx-circle-progress component:

component html:

```
<div class="clearfix">

  <div class="c100" [ngClass]="['p' + value, isBig ? 'big' : 'small', color]">
    <span>{{value}}%</span>
    <div class="slice">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

component ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-circle-progress',
  templateUrl: './ngx-circle-progress.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ngx-circle-progress.component.scss']
})
export class FsCircleProgressComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() isBig: boolean = true;
  @Input() value: number = 0;
  @Input() color: string = 'green';

   classes = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

component scss:

```
/****************************************************************
 *
 * CSS Percentage Circle
 * Author: Andre Firchow
 *
*****************************************************************/

// Compass utilities
@import "~compass-mixins/lib/compass";


// VARS
$circle-width: 0.08em;
$circle-width-hover: 0.04em;

// colors default
$primary-color: #307bbb;
$secondary-color: #ccc;
$bg-color: #f5f5f5;

$primary-color-green: #4db53c;
$primary-color-orange: #dd9d22;


// colors dark skin
$primary-color-dark: #c6ff00;
$secondary-color-dark: #777;
$bg-color-dark: #666;

$primary-color-green-dark: #5fd400;
$primary-color-orange-dark: #e08833;



// CIRCLE
// classes 2 extend
.rect-auto{
    clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}

.pie {
    position: absolute;
    border: $circle-width solid $primary-color;
    width: 1 - (2 * $circle-width);
    height: 1 - (2 * $circle-width);
    clip: rect(0em, 0.5em, 1em, 0em);
    border-radius: 50%;
    @include rotate(0deg);
}

.pie-fill {
    @include rotate(180deg);
}



// main
.c100 {

    *, *:before, *:after {
        @include box-sizing(content-box);
    }

    position: relative;
    font-size: 120px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0.1em 0.1em 0;
    background-color: $secondary-color;

    // center circle to its parent
    &.center{
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    // bigger size
    &.big{
        font-size: 240px;
    }

    // smaller size
    &.small{
        font-size: 80px;
    }

    // centered value inside circle
    > span {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 5em;
        line-height: 5em;
        font-size: 0.2em;
        color: $secondary-color;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        @include transition-property(all);
        @include transition-duration(0.2s);
        @include transition-timing-function(ease-out);
    }

    // background inside the circle
    &:after{
        position: absolute;
        top: $circle-width;
        left: $circle-width;
        display: block;
        content: " ";
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: $bg-color;
        width: 1 - (2 * $circle-width);
        height: 1 - (2 * $circle-width);
        @include transition-property(all);
        @include transition-duration(0.2s);
        @include transition-timing-function(ease-in);

    }

    // the slice (mask)
    .slice {
        position: absolute;
        width: 1em;
        height: 1em;
        clip: rect(0em, 1em, 1em, 0.5em);
    }

    // circle to show the status
    .bar {
        @extend .pie;
    }


    // loop to create all needed elements automatically
    @for $j from 51 through 100 {

        &.p#{$j} .slice {
            @extend .rect-auto;
        }

        &.p#{$j} .bar:after{
            @extend .pie-fill;
        }

        &.p#{$j} .fill{
            @extend .pie;
            @extend .pie-fill;
        }

    }

    // loop to rotate all 100 circles
    @for $j from 1 through 100 {
        &.p#{$j} .bar {
            @include rotate((360/100*$j) + deg);
        }
    }



    // hover styles
    &:hover{

        cursor: default;

        > span {
            width: 3.33em;
            line-height: 3.33em;
            font-size: 0.3em;
            color: $primary-color;
        }

        &:after{
            top: $circle-width-hover;
            left: $circle-width-hover;
            width: 1 - (2 * $circle-width-hover);
            height: 1 - (2 * $circle-width-hover);
        }

    }


    // override colors for the dark skin
    &.dark {

        background-color: $secondary-color-dark;

        .bar,
        .fill{
            border-color: $primary-color-dark !important;
        }

        > span {
            color: $secondary-color-dark;
        }


        &:after{
            background-color: $bg-color-dark;
        }

        &:hover{

            > span {
                color: $primary-color-dark;
            }

        }

    }


    // green skin
    &.green{

        .bar, .fill { border-color: $primary-color-green !important;}

        &:hover{
            > span { color: $primary-color-green;}
        }

    }

        &.green.dark{

            .bar, .fill { border-color: $primary-color-green-dark !important;}

            &:hover{
                > span { color: $primary-color-green-dark;}
            }

        }


    // orange skin
    &.orange{

        .bar, .fill { border-color: $primary-color-orange !important;}

        &:hover{
            > span { color: $primary-color-orange;}
        }

    }

        &.orange.dark{

            .bar, .fill { border-color: $primary-color-orange-dark !important;}

            &:hover{
                > span { color: $primary-color-orange-dark;}
            }

        }


}
```

You'd need to install this:

```
 npm install compass-mixins --save
```

Then you can use it in your component as follows:

```
<ngx-circle-progress [value]="10"></ngx-circle-progress>
```