# Circular progress bar with two levels on angular

Tags: angular

[Circular progress bar in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44536406/circular-progress-bar-in-angular-2) - I would like to modify the fill with two values. But when I try to change the code as below:

My TS file

```js
    @Input() value: number = 0;
    @Input() value1: number = 0;
```

My HTML

```html
    <div class="c100" [ngClass]="['p' + value + value1, isBig ? 'big' : 'small', color]">
          <span>{{value}}%</span>
          <div class="slice">
              <div class="bar"></div>
              <div class="fill"></div>
              <div class="fill1"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

It gives error as below:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[value,' is not a valid attribute name.
Error: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[value,' is not a valid attribute name.
    at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.setAttribute (vendor.js:74732)
    at BaseAnimationRenderer.setAttribute (vendor.js:73720)
    at setUpAttributes (vendor.js:25109)
    at ɵɵelementStart (vendor.js:35714)
    at Module.ɵɵelement (vendor.js:35784)
    at ReqappdashboardComponent_Template (main.js:5618)
    at executeTemplate (vendor.js:29134)
    at renderView (vendor.js:28943)
    at renderComponent (vendor.js:30204)
    at renderChildComponents (vendor.js:28802)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:1020)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:972)
```

Answer (score 0):

First check that `value` and `value1` are valid number or strings

If you want to achieve an operation on `value` + `value1` you should group them first

```
<div class="c100" [ngClass]="['p' + (value + value1), isBig ? 'big' : 'small', color]">
    <span>{{value}}%</span>
    <div class="slice">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
        <div class="fill1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mk5v4g?file=src/app/app.component.ts